# GWT UIBinding cannot find zero-arg constructor

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm trying my hand at the new GWT 2.0 UIBinder capability, and I have a ui XML that looks like this:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui" xmlns:my='urn:import:com.mystuff.mypackage'>
<g:VerticalPanel>
      <!-- other stuff -->
  <my:FileUploadPanel.ValidatingFileUpload styleName="field" ui:field="fileUpload" />
</g:VerticalPanel>
```

ValidatingFileUpload is a non-static inner class contained in FileUploadPanel that extends the FileUpload GWT class. It has an explicit zero-arg constructor that simply calls `super()`. However, when GWT starts up, I get this error:

```
00:00:18.359 [ERROR] Rebind result 'com.mystuff.mypackage.FileUploadPanel.ValidatingFileUpload' has no default (zero argument) constructors.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mystuff.mypackage.FileUploadPanel$ValidatingFileUpload.<init>()
```

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: I haven't been able to use UIBinder with widgets which are inner classes. Does it work if you pull the inner class out?

Comment: For what it's worth, I got the functionality I need without having to override the FileUpload class by using a `@UiHandler`-annotated method instead. So I guess this particular question is moot - still, I'd like to definitively hear if using inner classes like this is verboten.

Comment: I think it is the non-static inner class which is the problem. Can you make it a static inner class? If its a non-static class, GWT would have to make an object of the outer class as well (my guess), and that's where things break..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-static inner class needs to be instantiated within an instance of its containing class. This prohibits UiBinder from instantiating it when needed. Try using a static nested class instead.